# Openlayers 3 with cordova android has 10m cap

Tags: openlayers, cordova

I have been using the [standard geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) with my apps for a few years now.  a few months ago I noticed that all of my devices started to get really inaccurate.  And then this week a put the two together and realized it was the plugin which was causing the issue.  I'm not sure if I accidentally updated it or what, but it now uses the browser itself instead of a native Android approach like before.  Which means that it caps the accuracy to 10m (i'm not sure why).

I tried to revert to an older version and also tried another plugin which uses the Android approach which did solve the accuracy cap, but created a new problem in that there would be rendering issues where (mostly on newer devices) the map would just go blank when moving it to the user's location.

Can anyone shed any light on my situation?  If you have an OpenLayers map rendering well with cordova without the 10m cap, could you please share what you are using for it?  By that I mean, plugin name and version, plus what ever else may be relevant (cordova cli version?).

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: The 10m cap is due to google play services.  You can either use a version of the geolocation plugin which doesn't use play services or make sure you have an up to date version of them.  Was fixed a month or so ago I believe.